# Openerp: setting default grouping on a filter with no name

Tags: odoo

I'm referencing to the "Contracts" view, installed by the account_analytic_analysis module (Odoo 8, but the same thing is for Openerp 7).
I have been asked to group contracts by parent analytic account. 
The filter "Parent" has no "name" attribute set, while the examples I've found reference the name of the filter in the "context" of the action to define a default group_by.
Hence I inherited the searchview, adding a name attribute this way:

```
<xpath expr="//filter[@string='Parent']" position="attributes">
   <attribute name="name">parent</attribute>
</xpath>
```

then in the action:

```
<field name="search_view_id" ref="my_module.id_of_redefined_searchview" />
<field name="context">{'group_by':'parent'}</field>
```

Anyway it doesn't work, executing the action fails with error "KeyError: 'parent'", it seems that the system isn't using the new search view: in the action properties page, in the web client, everything seems ok, including the new searchview_id that is correctly identified.
Have you got any hint?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in the action' `context`:
the right form is `<field name="context">{'search_default_parent':1}</field>`
The "group_by" is implicit in the filter definition.